# How to use PathCchCanonicalizeEx with C++Builder 10.2?

Tags: c++builder, borland-c++, c++builder-10.2-tokyo

I have a legacy Windows project using the legacy 32 Bit C++ compiler. For various reasons I need to use the Windows 8+ function [PathCchCanonicalizeEx](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/71038645/how-do-i-need-to-integrate-windows-sdks-into-existing-project-in-cbuilder-10-2). C++Builder seems to provide the header and some module definition file for that, but I can't find any library to link against:

```
[ilink32 Error] Error: Unresolved external 'PathCchCanonicalizeEx' referenced from C:\[...]\WIN32\DEBUG\TMP\FILE.OBJ
```

**How am I supposed to fix this?** Do I need to add a [Windows 8.1 SDK](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/71038645/how-do-i-need-to-integrate-windows-sdks-into-existing-project-in-cbuilder-10-2)? Is the necessary lib simply named differently and I can't find it? Something completely different?

Comment: Are you linking to `Pathcch.lib`? If so, and you are still getting the error, then the `.lib` is outdated. You *could* try generating a new `.lib` from the appropriate `.dll`.  Or simply importing the function manually using `LoadLibrary()`+`GetProcAddress()` (or the linker's delay-load feature). But that means knowing which DLL to use. See [Which DLL has PathCchAppend?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57354840/), for instance.

Comment: The problem is that I can't find the file `Pathcch.lib` in my installation of C++Builder at all. That's the first thing I wonder about, the headers are available, the lib is not. Is that correct or not already? So I really need to create the lib from my available Windows DLL on my own? And that is preferred over using the lib from some Windows SDK?

Comment: As you noted in your [other question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/71038645/), you can't use the `.lib` files from the SDK, because they are meant for Visual C++, not C++Builder. Embarcadero is responsible for shipping C++Builder compatible `.lib` files from the SDK, and any it doesn't will have to be created manually using the IMPLIB or MKEXP tool.

Answer (score 0):

According my tests, one has two options:

1. [IMPLIB/MKEXP](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/71247653/whats-the-difference-between-implib-and-mkexp-in-cbuilder-to-create-import-li?noredirect=1&lq=1)

I'm developing/testing a some Windows 10 21H2, which provides an implementation for `PathCchCanonicalizeEx` in some DLL already. So if that source DLL is known, one can use `IMPLIB` or `MKEXP` to create an import library manually. I did that and after adding the created library from `IMPLIB` to my project, the linker errors were instantly gone.

Though, it's not that easy to know where `PathCchCanonicalizeEx` [is placed in](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57354840/which-dll-has-pathcchappend). One pretty easily finds the `api-ms-win-core-path-l1-1-0.dll`, but that thing is NOT an actual file on the disk and therefore can't be used by `IMPLIB` or `MKEXP`. That name is only a virtual concept for the library loader to address the same named API set of modern Windows, the extension `.dll` doesn't mean it's a file at all.

> You can use an API set name in the context of a loader operation such as LoadLibrary or P/Invoke instead of a DLL module name to ensure a correct route to the implementation no matter where the API is actually implemented on the current device. However, when you do this you must append the string .dll at the end of the contract name. This is a requirement of the loader to function properly, and is not considered actually a part of the contract name. Although contract names appear similar to DLL names in this context, they are fundamentally different from DLL module names and do not directly refer to a file on disk.

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/apiindex/windows-apisets#api-set-contract-names

What you really need to work with is `KernelBase.dll`, which is even [documented by MS](https://github.com/MicrosoftDocs/sdk-api/blob/docs/sdk-api-src/content/pathcch/nf-pathcch-pathcchappend.md).

```
implib "KernelBase x86.lib"    C:\Windows\SysWOW64\KernelBase.dll
implib "KernelBase x86-64.lib" C:\Windows\System32\KernelBase.dll
```

2. [Module Definition File](https://docwiki.embarcadero.com/RADStudio/Sydney/en/Module_Definition_Files)

The downside of manually creating LIB files is that one needs to maintain those with the project. Things depend on if the target is 32 or 64 Bit, DEBUG or RELEASE, so paths might become a bit complex, one might need to create relative paths for libraries in the project settings using placeholders for the target and stuff like that.

It seems that all of this can be avoided with [Module Definition Files](https://blogs.embarcadero.com/how-to-build-and-use-a-simple-dll/), which's purpose is to provide IMPORT and EXPORT statements to either consume exported functions by other DLLs or make that possible for others with own functions. I've successfully resolved my linker problems by simply creating a file named like my app using the extension `.def` alongside my other project files. That file needs to be added to the project, though.

```
dbxml.cbproj
dbxml.cbproj.local
dbxml.cpp
dbxml.def
dbxml.res
[...]
```

The following content made the app use the correct function from the correct DLL. Though, what didn't work was using the API set name, which resulted in an error message by the linker.

```
IMPORTS
    KernelBase.PathCchCanonicalizeEx
```

```
IMPORTS
    api-ms-win-core-path-l1-1-0.PathCchCanonicalizeEx
```

> [ilink32 Error] Invalid command line switch for "ilink32". Parameter "ItemSpec" cannot be null.

> [ilink32 Error] Fatal: Error processing .DEF file

The latter is after restarting C++Builder, so I guess the format of the file is simply wrong because of the API set name.