# What's the difference between IMPLIB and MKEXP in C++Builder to create import libraries?

Tags: c++builder, borland-c++, c++builder-10.2-tokyo

After [asking](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/71038891/how-to-use-pathcchcanonicalizeex-with-cbuilder-10-2) how to use `PathCchCanonicalizeEx` with C++Builder 10.2, I was [told](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/71038891/how-to-use-pathcchcanonicalizeex-with-cbuilder-10-2#comment125603291_71038891) to create missing import libraries using the tools `IMPLIB` or `MKEXP`. I've tested both apps and they are creating lib files based on `KernelBase.dll` of my Windows 10. Though, both file contents look different, they start with different headers, are differently large overall etc. `MKEXP` documents to `Creates an import archive from an input file`, but doesn't seem to explain what that actually means.

**So, when to use which of the both tools? What is the difference in purpose, how they work, possibly what they do support, etc?**

Comment: implib is there from the old days, I do not know mkexp maybe they add it in later versions of BCB (I am stuck with BDS2006 and there it is not present). All the versions of implib I have used over the years knows only 32bit DLLs so I just guess the mkexp may be used for 64bit DLLs ...

Comment: @Spektre that is exactly the difference. IMPLIB is for 32bit only, MKEXP is for 64bit only. Support for 64bit development was added to C++Builder in XE3.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[`IMPLIB`](https://docwiki.embarcadero.com/RADStudio/en/IMPLIB.EXE,_the_Import_Library_Tool_for_Win32) is for generating an import lib for a 32bit DLL.

[`MKEXP`](https://docwiki.embarcadero.com/RADStudio/en/MKEXP.EXE,_the_64-bit_Windows_Import_Library_Tool_for_C%2B%2B) is for generating an import lib for a 64bit DLL.

Comment: What does `for a [...] DLL` mean in this context? I've successfully executed both tools with the same 32 Bit source DLLs and `MKEXP` seems to create the same file for 32 Bit and 64 Bit source DLLs. So it's about the target EXE/DLL? `MKEXP` supports 64 Bit targets only or additionally to 32 Bit?

Comment: @ThorstenSchöning IMPLIB is for 32bit targets, and MKEXP is for 64bit targets. The documentation makes that pretty clear.

Comment: @ThorstenSchöning "*MKEXP seems to create the same file for 32 Bit and 64 Bit source DLLs*" - I have never heard of MKEXP supporting 32bit DLLs, and I've never tried it.  It is documented as being for 64bit only, no mention of 32bit.