# How to securely dynamically load PathAllocCanonicalize at runtime

Tags: winapi, visual-c++

I have a Windows desktop C++ application that currently uses [`::PathCanonicalizeW`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/shlwapi/nf-shlwapi-pathcanonicalizew). As you can see from the documentation, it was introduced in Windows 2000 and is located in `shlwapi.dll`. In order to support long paths on Win 10+, I need to start using [`::PathAllocCanonicalize`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/pathcch/nf-pathcch-pathalloccanonicalize) (or one of it's friends - `::PathCchCanonicalize` or `::PathCchCanonicalizeEx`).

This function was added in Windows 8, but I still need to support the older OS's. In order to support all OS's, I need to dynamically load `::PathAllocCanonicalize` by calling `::LoadLibrary` at runtime. The problem is that the documentation doesn't provide the DLL that includes this function.

After doing some searching, I found [this documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/uwp/win32-and-com/win32-apis) that includes all 3 of the new PathCanonicalize functions and it claims that they are in `api-ms-win-core-path-l1-1-0.dll`. After more searching, it appears that this is not a traditional DLL because there is no file anywhere in the OS with that name. This application has always loaded system libraries using the full path to the file in the system directory (typically `C:\Windows\system32`) to make sure that it's not loading malicious DLLs, but for this it will be impossible without a physical file to point to.

I have been able to test that calling `::LoadLibrary("api-ms-win-core-path-l1-1-0.dll")` does work, but the fact that that documentation mentions UWP worries me. Is there any documentation for the supported way to dynamically load these kinds of functions at runtime in a desktop app? Is there a more secure way to load this DLL?

P.S. This app cannot be deployed with that DLL, and even if it were possible there's no point since any OS that doesn't have that function wouldn't have full support for long paths anyway. Using the documented `pathcch.lib` would require upgrading the target Windows version. Dropping support for the older OS's is also completely out of the question. The function must be manually dynamically loaded at runtime.

Comment: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/apiindex/detect-api-set-availability

Comment: It seems to be exported from kernelbase.dll which presumably redirects to the correct DLL.

Comment: How did you find that it's exported from kernelbase.dll? I wouldn't want to rely on something that isn't documented.

Comment: @SeanHall Read up about [Windows API sets](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/apiindex/windows-apisets) in general.  In particular interest is that it talks about how API sets are loaded in contexts like `LoadLibrary()`.

Comment: I read that before posting my answer. It assumes you are already running on Windows 10+. If you simply pass the API set name with the `.dll` extension, you are opening yourself up to loading the wrong thing on older OS's that don't do the magic. The lack of the API set in the function's documentation is what caused all of this confusion, I would have just stuck with that if it was there by itself without the DLL.

Comment: The term *"delay load"* describes a different technique (see [Linker support for delay-loaded DLLs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cpp/build/reference/linker-support-for-delay-loaded-dlls)). For that you only need to specify the documented import library (Pathcch.lib). While that is an option you could use, this question seems to be asking about [run-time dynamic linking](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/dlls/run-time-dynamic-linking). This is a slightly different technique (with delay-loading using run-time dynamic linking).

Comment: Thanks, I updated the question to not use the term "delay load".

Comment: Api sets are pointless for desktop apps. For something like this I would grep shlwapi > kernel32 > kernelbase > ntdll when the documentation is lacking.

Answer (score 3):

As pointed out by Hans, `api-ms-win-core-path-l1-1-0` is known as an API set along with many others starting with `api-ms-win-core`. Based on the documentation there, it appears that the documentation for `PathAllocCanonicalize` is incomplete. It should list the API set on that page along with the DLL for desktop apps. Looking at the source on GitHub, it looks like there is a bug with that page and the other `pathcch` functions where that information is in the header but not rendered onto the page. That header lists `api-ms-win-core-path-l1-1-0.dll` and `KernelBase.dll`.

If for some reason I wanted to continue to load the API set instead of `KernelBase.dll`, `::LoadLibraryExW(L"api-ms-win-core-path-l1-1-0.dll", NULL, LOAD_LIBRARY_SEARCH_SYSTEM32)` worked which would be just as secure as specifying the full path to a DLL in the system32 folder. Note that `LOAD_LIBRARY_SEARCH_SYSTEM32` was not supported without KB2533623 on RTM versions of Vista, Windows 7, Server 2008, and Server 2008 R2 so that might not actually be secure on those OS's.

Comment: kernelbase is an implementation detail.

Comment: @Joshua This is what I'm trying to learn, are you sure? Do you know of any API that only has the API set documented and not any DLL?

Comment: The dll is that api-ms-win-core dll. Apparently it's some kind of magic name so your LoadLibraryEx call is fine. But note that it will not be there on old enough Windows so you will need to handle getting NULL back and synthesizing it.

Comment: [`QueryOptionalDelayLoadedAPI`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/libloaderapi2/nf-libloaderapi2-queryoptionaldelayloadedapi) only has the API set documented, but its header in Github also has `kernelbase.dll` along with several API sets. I wish I could find something official one way or the other. I understand making non-Desktop apps use the API set name, but for Desktop apps it seems odd to me that you have to rely on the magic name and not a physical DLL.

Comment: Apparently there was a very similar question here - https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57354840/which-dll-has-pathcchappend. I'm going to avoid API sets since the redirection provides no benefits to a desktop app. Microsoft has recommended probing for features instead of version checks, and this redirection seems like it could interfere with the probing.